# Separating Redux Async Middleware and general API functions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, code-splitting

I am currently using createAsyncThunk to create async middlewares for a React-Redux app I am working on in the following manner:

```
import axios from "axios";
import ApiUrls from "../ApiUrls";
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

class NftMiddleware{

//The middleware
  static fetchAllNfts = createAsyncThunk('nft/fetchAllNfts', async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(ApiUrls.getAllNftsUrl);
        return response.data;
    });

}
```

Now if I want to also create a wrapper function for a fetch request without triggering any dispatch, should I add another static function to the NftMiddleware class like so:

```
class NftMiddleware{

//The middleware
  static fetchAllNfts = createAsyncThunk('nft/fetchAllNfts', async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(ApiUrls.getAllNftsUrl);
        return response.data;
    });

//Not actually middleware, just a simple api call wrapper
    static postMetaData = async (data) => {
        const response = await axios.post(ApiUrls.postMetaData, data);
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of organizing my code that interacts with the backend? Should these be separate classes? For middleware and then for actual API calls? I can't help but feel I am doing things in an 'unclean' and unintuitive manner, as opposed to a more 'centralized' way.